# Compare table rows, prevent duplicates

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to add row from one table to another, there's also datepicker and I want to check if dates match.

```
int i=jTable1.getSelectedRow();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
jXDatePicker1.setFormats(dateFormat);
String date = dateFormat.format(jXDatePicker1.getDate()).toString();
String c1=jTable1.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
String c2=jTable1.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
String c3=jTable1.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
String c4=jTable1.getValueAt(i, 3).toString();
String c5=price.getText().toString();
String c6=jTextField1.getText().toString();
String c7=date;
model.addRow(new Object[]{c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7});
jTable2.setModel(model);
while(jTable2.getRowCount()>1) {
    for (int k = 0; k < jTable2.getRowCount(); k++) {
        if (c7.equals(jTable2.getValueAt(k, 6).toString())) {
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record exist");
        model.removeRow(jTable2.getRowCount()-1);
        return;
    }
}
```

It throws error even though the dates are different:

[image]

Nothing seems to work I tried to compare ids instead of dates

```
while(jTable2.getRowCount()>1) {
            for (int k = 0; k < jTable2.getRowCount(); k++) {
                int t1=Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt(k, 0).toString());
                if (c1==t1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record exist");
                    model.removeRow(jTable2.getRowCount()-1);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

parsed both values as int still nothing. My loop doesn't work

Comment: I fixed your indentation. I hope it is clear now that your if statement does nothing.

Comment: Changed to still doesnt work
while(jTable2.getRowCount()>1) {
    for (int k = 0; k < jTable2.getRowCount(); k++) {
        if (c7.equals(jTable2.getValueAt(k, 6).toString())) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record exist");
        model.removeRow(jTable2.getRowCount()-1);
        return;
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your if statement does nothing as mentioned.

Otherwise, instead of comparing the two dates as string, make them Date then compare them.

Just change those lines:

```
Date date = dateFormat.parse(jXDatePicker1.getDate().toString());
//your code
Date c7=date;
```

And then your if statement whould be:

```
Date rowDate= dateFormat.parse(jTable2.getValueAt(k, 6).toString());

if (c7.compareTo(rowDate)==0) { //the two dates are equal
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record exist");
                model.removeRow(jTable2.getRowCount()-1);
                return;
    }
```

Comment: I edited my post, since doesn't work. If statement isn't executed but I don't know why.

Comment: @user3316744 your if doesn' work beacause there isn't any code inside it put the action inside it, before the `}`, like in my answer.